# Download image in form in Electron app and draw it by canvas don't work, what may i do?

Tags: javascript, electron

I try to downloade local image in the form and draw it by canvas, but it don't work
Help please

```
document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", download);
//...
let link = document.createElement("a");
link.download = `${code.value}.png`;
link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
//...
ctx.save();
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.restore();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<label>Image File:</label><br/>
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/>
<canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>

var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function handleImage(e){
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
}
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);     
}
```